# Python interprocess communication with idle processes

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing, pipe, interprocess

I have an idle background process to process data in a queue, which I've implemented in the following way. The data passed in this example is just an integer, but I will be passing lists with up to 1000 integers and putting up to 100 lists on the queue per sec. Is this the correct approach, or should I be looking at more elaborate RPC and server methods?

```
import multiprocessing
import Queue
import time

class MyProcess(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, queue, cmds):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)  
        self.q = queue
        self.cmds = cmds

    def run(self):
        exit_flag = False
        while True:
            try:
                obj = self.q.get(False)
                print obj
            except Queue.Empty:
                if exit_flag:
                    break
                else:
                    pass
            if not exit_flag and self.cmds.poll():
                cmd = self.cmds.recv()
                if cmd == -1:
                    exit_flag = True
            time.sleep(.01)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    proc2main, main2proc = multiprocessing.Pipe(duplex=False)
    p = MyProcess(queue, proc2main)
    p.start()
    for i in range(5):
        queue.put(i)    
    main2proc.send(-1)
    proc2main.close()
    main2proc.close()
    # Wait for the worker to finish
    queue.close()
    queue.join_thread()
    p.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how long it will take to process the data. I can't tell because I don't have a sample of the data, but in general it is better to move to more elaborate RPC and server methods when you need things like load balancing, guaranteed uptime, or scalability. Just remember that these things will add complexity, which may make your application harder to deploy, debug, and maintain. It will also increase the latency that it takes to process a task (which might or might not be a concern to you).

I would test it with some sample data, and determine if you need the scalability that multiple servers provide.